# repair system after deliting extended partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted, data-recovery

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I have a 1TB hard disk with dual boot Ubuntu-Windows10.
Some months ago I have freed some space to create another partition to install CentOS but then I no longer needed to install it and the partition remained there.
Today I was willing to give back this space to my Ubuntu installation  and so I started by deliting the useless partition but into `gnome-disks` there was four partitions (or that was what I stupidly fought):

1. Windows system reserved
2. Window primary partition
3. file system partition
4. Extended partition

The `1` and `2` was clearly the Windows 10 partitions (NFAT) and the `3` was the Ubuntu partition so I assumed that the Extended partition was the useless one because I'm used to my laptop partitioning ware ubuntu takes only one partition but then, after deliting it I realized my mistake...
Rebooting the system brought grub to not identify the partition (of course) and trying to manually point to the partition failed.
In an attempt to solve the problem I booted up on an Ubuntu 20.04 USB Live and tried to repair the mistake using `boot-repair` with the hope that the problem was just grub not identifying it but it didn't worked (at least now I can boot on windows so it was not completely useless).

So my question is:
How can I repair my system partition brokend by deliting the extended partition?

(In case it's needed I know how big it was)

**EDIT:**

Solved by using `testdisk` as suggested by [emk2203](https://askubuntu.com/users/332437/emk2203)

Comment: What's inside the Extended partition? Please run _sudo lshw -short -C disk ; lsblk | grep -v  loop  ; df -h | grep -v loop ; sudo blkid ; dmesg | grep '/dev/sd'   ; dmesg | grep '/dev/nvm'_ then highlight the resulting text and copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C . Return here, click [edit], and paste the resulting text into the question  so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Did you try `testdisk` already? It should be able to correctly guess the deleted partition information. More info at https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @emk2203 I didn't tried it until now but it worked so please answer the question so I can give you the credits for the solution instead of answering it myself ☺️❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution credits to [emk2203](https://askubuntu.com/users/332437/emk2203) :**

To solve the problem the first thing is to recover the delited partition.
In order to do so is useful to use a program like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) following the instructions [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and summarised there and then make your partition one of the bootable options of grub.

### Recover partition with `TestDisk`

1. After TestDisk is installed run it as superuser (`sudo ./` followed by the directory to the executable file of `TestDisk`) and choose the "log creation" choice you prefer using <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> and proceed with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   [image: step 1 illustration]
2. With <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> choose the disk where the partition was and with <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> select `proceed`.
   [image: step 2 illustration]
3. With the same controls used since now choose the "partition table".
   If you don't know which partition is the correct one notice that probably `TastDisk` have detected it and if so you will see it written below.
   [image: step 3 illustration]
4. Now select `analyse`...
   [image: step 4 illustration]
5. And then run a `Quick search`...
   [image: step 5 illustration]
6. At the end of the quick search you should notice your lost partition be added to the partition list and therefore you can naw press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue.
   If the partition you was looking for is still missing press <kbd>Enter</kbd> anyway but pay attention to the next step.
   [image: step 6 illustration]
7. Now if the missing partition is listed to restore it select the `write` option. If instead you still don't see it go for a `deeper search` and then go back to `step 6`.
   [image: you guess it... Step 7 illustration]
8. The partition he's been successfully restored but to be sure that grub recognize it as a bootable option follow the second part of this answer.

### Reconfigure grub with `boot-repair`

To install boot repair you just need to add the repository and install it with `apt` like for most programs.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

Now you can lounch it typing the `boot-repair` command and with the GUI select  <kbd>recommended repair</kbd>

[image: boot-repair GUI]

Then after a pop-up asking information about the log handling it will almost certainly automatically configure grub to boot on your partition again.

Comment: Very nice answer! Upvoted. Much better than what I would have written. ;-)